# C# Serialization in MongoDb - _id on nested type, and some properties with private setters

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, bson

I'm in a position where I need to serialize some complex documents into MongoDb, but I can't change the class definition as I don't have control over the source.

However, we need to ensure that callers can still use Linq, so we need to map the class correclty into MongoDb.

Current there are few issues we're faced with:

> 1. The `_id`_ representation is on a nested class.
> 2. There are properties with private setters that need to be serialized/ deserialzied.

The shape of the class looks a little like this:

```
public class AggregateType : AggregateBase
{
    public int IntProperty { get; private set; }

    public ComplexObject ComplexObjectProperty { get; private set; }
}
```

With `AggregateBase` looking like this:

```
abstract public class AggregateBase
{
    public AggregateDetails Details { get; set; }
}
```

And finally:

```
public class AggregateDetails
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    ...other properties
}
```

On the base class `AggregateBase`, there is a property called `Details` which contains the `Id` of the aggregate, which is a `Guid`. This `Id` field needs to be mapped to the `ObjectId` or `_id` field within a MongoDb document.

I need to be able to serialize the document, forcing the use of the `Details.Id` as the `_id`, and have the private setters serialized too.

I've done this with CosmoDb using a custom `JsonContractResolver` without issue. But the move to MongoDb has proved a little more complex.

It's worth noting that there are many `AggregateType` classes, all with a different shape. I'd like to find a generic way of serializing them, without having to write lots of specific mappers if possible - much like we do with CosmoDb.

On top of that, we would need this solution to work with the Linq query provider for MongoDb too.

Comment: Try using the `[BsonId]` ontop of the Id field that you need , that should indicate to the driver to interpret that property as the UID.

Comment: Thanks @cl0ud, but I'm not in a position to modify the class implementations.

Answer (score 1):

Ive thought a little about this , the only way I can see this working is if you create matching types that will serve as your POCO for inserting into mongodb. Im going to assume you are using the C# Driver for Mongo.

```
public class AggregateTypeDocument : AggregateBaseDocument
{
   public int IntProperty { get; private set; }
   public ComplexObject ComplexObjectProperty { get; private set; }
}

abstract public class AggregateBaseDocument
{
   public AggregateDetailsDocument Details { get; private set; }
}

 public class AggregateDetailsDocument 
 {
    [BsonId]
    public Guid Id { get; private set; }
    ...other properties
 }
```

You will end up replicating the structure but just be appending Document at the end for this example. By no means do you have to conform to this

Now you can mold your types to be more mongo friendly using various attributes.

The next step would be to either in your repository ( or wherever ) to map the types with class definitions you don't have access to to your new mongo friendly ones.

I would suggest [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/) for this or plain old instantiation. Now you should be able to safely operate on the collection. See below example for automapper.

```
  var normalAggregateType = new AggregateType(); 

  var client = new MongoClient("yourconnectionstring");
  var db = client.GetDatabase("mydatabase");

  var collection = db.GetCollection<AggregateTypeDocument>("myaggregatetypes");

  var mongoAggregateType = Mapper.Map<AggregateTypeDocument>(normalAggregateType);

  collection.InsertOne(mongoAggregateType);
```

Comment: Although im sure there is the option to use reflection in this case to add the bsonId attribute to the class at runtime

Comment: I guess I would need to auto-generate the document types of the aggregates, because there are many aggregate types in the system. The second problem would be using the Linq querying. From the callers point of view, they'd have to make sure they use the Document version, and then map back again.

Comment: @Kieron Possibly using reflection and adding the BsonId attribute onto the objects properties as they get inserted is another option. Its gonna be an expensive operation though.